# Scatter graph with desired series name

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[image: Table data]

I have the above table, but however I try I cannot get the evidence gap to appear as individual series.

In this example there should be a total of 4 points with the legend of the points being Test, Test 1, Test 2 and Test 3. The plotting should be the Strategic Alignment on the Y axis and Impact on the X axis (although it doesn't matter if this is the reverse)

Every time I try it Impact has the series name or (if I switch row/column), 8 points on the scatter being marked:

[image: Series wrong]

[image: Series right, but multiple points]

Any help would be great - I thought it would be something simple to plot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Only Select the data range (`B2:C5`) and insert the chart
2. Select the Data Series in the chart

[image]

3. Right-click on the data series and choose "Add Data Labels" from the dropdown menu
4. Select the labels, Right-click on them and choose "Format Data Labels" from the dropdown menu
5. Under "Label Contains", check the "Value From Cells" box and choose the range with the desired labels (in this case `A2:A5`)

Final result should look like this:

[image]